# Java Wildfly javax.ejb.EJBException

Tags: java

I am working on project using java and wildfly 10. I have problem when I try to make rest request. I can not figure out where is the real problem.
Here is a project source code:
https://github.com/alien93/at
and here is error from consele
https://gist.github.com/MiselAdemi/f5876f6f4b2b6dffcfcf6598cd3ce903

Can somebody help me, or even just to give me some hint?

Answer (score 1):

Relevant part of the stacktrace is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to session.HostsList
at session.HostBean.register(HostBean.java:71)
```

When we take a look to the row 71 in HostBean.java, we will find following:

```
return (HostsList) Host.hosts;
```

As stacktrace says, `Host.hosts` is not a `HostList`. Also it cannot be because type of of `hosts` is something that implements java.util.List, in this case runtime type is ArrayList:

```
public transient static List<Host> hosts = new ArrayList<Host>();
```

`HostList` can be constructed and then returned as follows (in line 71 in HostBean.java):

```
HostsList hl = new HostList();
hl.setHosts(host.hosts);
return hosts;
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestion what is the best way to correct this in this project?

Comment: Added to answer how to fix this very local problem, but cannot say is this best possible fix on context of whole project.